# What is the proper way to create an SKTileSet and SKTileMapNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

This is what I have:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    let tileSet = SKTileSet?(named: "Hexes")
    let map = SKTileMapNode(tileSet: tileSet, columns: 10, rows: 10, tileSize: .init(width: 20, height: 20))
}
```

According to the developer documentation this is corrects far as I can see, but I am getting the error: 'Extraneous argument label 'named:' in call'.

If I remove `(named: "Hexes")`, then I get: 'Expected member name or constructor call after type name', and the second line has multiple errors as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let tileSet = SKTileSet?(named: "Hexes")
```

The ? is not wanted there - you are calling a *failable initializer* which is one that returns an optional `SKTileSet.init(named:)` returns an *optional* `SKTileSet`, but you don't call it with a `?`

```
let tileSet = SKTileSet(named: "Hexes")
```

If you want to make the type explicit, you would write it like:

```
let tileSet: SKTileSet? = SKTileSet(named: "Hexes")
```